# PHP Countable count() or ->count()

Tags: php

When you have an object that implements countable interface should you use `$object->count()` or `count($object)`?

I understand that there is most likely very little difference, but if someone could explain if there is any difference at all, what that would technically be.

Comment: The only big difference I can see is when you call `count($object)` without the object implementing the `countable` interface. There is a nice example in the manual. http://php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php

Comment: Calling `count($object)` may be slightly slower, because internally it has to do additional checks (of what type the parameter is and if it implements `Countable`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`count()` can be used both on arrays and `Countable` objects. If you are using `$object->count()` you are restricting your function to just objects. Using `count()` you allow arrays too.

Apart from that there is no difference. You can see the implementation here: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c#L676

Comment: Ok that makes sense thanks.  Is there any technical difference when using $object->count and count($object) on objects, regardless of how small a difference?

Comment: count($object) actually just calls $object->count() anyway.

Comment: @SeanJohnson yep and that is making it a tiny bit slower - like 2-3 times.